# returning string between last occurrence of a character

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract a string that is between a comma "," and a closing bracket ")"

here is the string below...

`(Punta Gorda, FL, U.S.A.)`

From this I am looking to extract `U.S.A`

the regex that I am currently using returns `FL, U.S.A.`

this is done with the following regex `(?<=,).*(?=\))`

What is the easiest way to modify the regex in order to achieve my objective?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this one instead:

```
(?<=,\s)[^,]*(?=\))
```

Note that your regex would return whitespace before `FL, U.S.A`. This one does not.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have tested it with other inputs such as `United Kingdom` and it works well.

Answer (score 2):

If you don´t want to use Regex, this would work too:

```
$string = "(Punta Gorda, FL, U.S.A.)";
$last_occurence = strrpos($string, ",");
$country = substr($string, $last_occurence + 1, strlen($string) - $last_occurence - 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with this regex:

```
([^,\s]+)(?=\))
```

**UPD**:

```
$str = '(london, United kingdom)';

preg_match('~([^,]+)(?=\))~', $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Slight problem with this solution, it wouldn't register place like the UK e.g. `(london, United kingdom)`

Comment: @mk_89: updated, but you need to trim the value if necessary now